Spinning number animation on value update
On a site I have a number counter that always increases, without any fancy animation. Now I need to animate it every time the number updates, like this:

Which HTML (+CSS +JS if needed) code can I use for this? Thanks!
P.S.: The number has 2 decimals and uses "," as a decimal separator.

According to the illustration, this already unmaintained library came to mind:

odometer (github.com)

Example


const el = document.querySelector('.odometer')
 
const od = new Odometer({
  el: el,
  value: 1234, // default value
 
  // Any option (other than auto and selector) can be passed in here
  format: '( ddd),dd',
  theme: 'default',
})
 
// change to new value
od.update(9876)
// or
el.innerHTML = 9876
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-default.css" />
<script src="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js"></script>

<div class="odometer"></div>



Example with your design


const values = [4753, 8170]
const el = document.querySelector('.odometer')
const od = new Odometer({
  el: el,
  value: values[0], // default value
 
  // Any option (other than auto and selector) can be passed in here
  format: '( ddd),dd',
  theme: 'default',
})

let index = 1
function infiniteUpdate() {
  od.update(values[index])
  index = (index + 1) % values.length
  setTimeout(infiniteUpdate, 6000)
}
infiniteUpdate()
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend&display=swap');

body {
  background-color: #6c48ff;
}

.circle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #242400;
  border: 10px solid #fc6caa;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 37px;
}

/* change font-family */
.circle,
.odometer-value {
  font-family: 'Lexend', sans-serif;
}

/* change default duration from 3s to 5s */
/* https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/issues/91 */
.odometer.odometer-animating-up .odometer-ribbon-inner, .odometer.odometer-animating-down.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    -moz-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    -ms-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    -o-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    transition-duration: 5s !important;
}

/* add shadow */
.odometer::before, .odometer::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
}
.odometer::before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(36, 36, 0, 1), rgba(36, 36, 0, 0));
}
.odometer::after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(36, 36, 0, 1), rgba(36, 36, 0, 0));
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-default.css" />
<script src="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js"></script>

<div class="circle">
  <div>$</div>
  <div class="odometer"></div>
</div>



Example with separated fractional part

A quick idea for the decimal value: You can insert two odometers. The first one counts the whole number, the second one counts the fractional part. This way, you can handle them separately from each other.



const values = [100.2, 109.2]

const elNumber = document.querySelector('.odometer-number')
const odNumber = new Odometer({
  el: elNumber,
  value: parseInt(values[0].toString().split('.')[0]), // default value
 
  // Any option (other than auto and selector) can be passed in here
  format: '( ddd)',
  theme: 'default',
})

const elFract = document.querySelector('.odometer-fractional')
const odFract = new Odometer({
  el: elFract,
  value: parseInt(values[0].toString().split('.')[1]), // default value
 
  // Any option (other than auto and selector) can be passed in here
  format: 'd',
  theme: 'default',
})

let index = 1
function infiniteUpdate() {
  const value = values[index]
  const newNumber = parseInt(value.toString().split('.')[0])
  const newFract = parseInt(value.toString().split('.')[1])
  
  odNumber.update(newNumber)
  odFract.update(newFract)
  
  index = (index + 1) % values.length
  setTimeout(infiniteUpdate, 6000)
}
infiniteUpdate()
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend&display=swap');

body {
  background-color: #6c48ff;
}

.circle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #242400;
  border: 10px solid #fc6caa;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2px;
  
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 37px;
}

/* change font-family */
.circle,
.odometer-value {
  font-family: 'Lexend', sans-serif;
}

/* change default duration from 3s to 5s */
/* https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/issues/91 */
.odometer.odometer-animating-up .odometer-ribbon-inner, .odometer.odometer-animating-down.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    -moz-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    -ms-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    -o-transition-duration: 5s !important;
    transition-duration: 5s !important;
}

/* add shadow */
.odometer::before, .odometer::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
}
.odometer::before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(36, 36, 0, 1), rgba(36, 36, 0, 0));
}
.odometer::after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(36, 36, 0, 1), rgba(36, 36, 0, 0));
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-default.css" />
<script src="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js"></script>

<div class="circle">
  <div>$</div>
  <div class="odometer odometer-number"></div>
  <div>,</div>
  <div class="odometer odometer-fractional"></div>
</div>




Wow, this is quite awesome @rozszoltan! Much appreciated! I just need 2 changes:

I'm passing a new value every X seconds (so no need to set the ranges). How can I make only the affected digits that change animate? I.e. if one value is 10,000.20 first and the next value is 10,009.20, I just want one digit to animate from "0" to "9"
Could you please update your code to use the font Lexend (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend)?


When updating the number, only the necessary digits are refreshed. I understand what you mean, keeping the non-changing digits fixed. Quickly scanning through the documentation, I couldn't find an immediate description for this, but the fractional part updates because it starts counting upwards: 10000.2, 10000.3, 10000.4, etc.

I added the font. The CSS styles will be applied based on their specificity. Since the .odometer-value already had a font-family, you can only override it by directly targeting this class's font-family. Additionally, I overridden the .circle due to the $ sign.

A quick idea for the decimal value: You can insert two odometers. The first one counts the whole number, the second one counts the fractional part. This way, you can handle them separately from each other.

I also added my previous idea titled "Example with separated fractional part". (Beauty error, but just for the sake of the example, I didn't search for the most perfect solution for splitting the float number. Therefore, I made a string out of it and split it along the dot.)

Note: Your font might not be the best for this purpose, as its characters have varying widths. A "jump" can be seen when switching from a wider digit to a narrower one. It might be beneficial to use a font where each character occupies the same width space. Such fonts are referred to as "monospace" fonts.

Amazing @rozsazoltan! You have fully solved my question. I've been able to implement exactly what I needed thanks to your solution. Thank you so much!
